# the types of access token

Tags: python, facebook

Try to get facebook access token, find that there several kinds of access token,
what is the difference between them ,for example, the user access token and the app access token,
when using:

```
graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_A‌​PP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

what access token I get, and what is the valid time, if I want to get a long-lived access token, how to get it

Answer (score 0):

This is explained very well in the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Here is another article about it: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

- Extended User Token: Valid for 60 days
- App Token: Valid forever
- Extended Page Token: Valid forever